# Eliminar Fila con Boton jquery

Tags: jquery

Estoy llenando una tabla de uno en uno, pero en caso de no querer algun dato ya, simplemente se elimine, esta es mi tabl con jquery

```
 var row = '';
    row += '<tr >';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px">' + XXXX+ '</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + XXXX+ '</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + XXX+ '</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + XXX+ '</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;"><button  class="btn btn-danger" onclick=\"Eliminar(\'' + ID+ '\')\">Eliminar</button> </td>';
$('#table').append(row);
```

Al dar clic en el boton eliminar mando como parametro el id de la fila que se quiere eliminar a una function

```
function Eliminar(ID)
{
  
    $("#table" + unidad).parent().parent().remove();

}
```

intento eliminar la fila de esta manera, pero no sucede nada, sin embargo si inspecciono el codigo, si esta tomando el Id.
de que manera puedo eliminar la fila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega una clase al boton y crea un manejador de click.  Luego, dentro del manejador utiliza `this`.  Asi:

```js
var row = '';
    row += '<tr >';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px">XXXX</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">XXXX</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">XXX</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;">XXX</td>';
    row += '<td style="padding:2px;"><button  class="btn btn-danger eliminar" >Eliminar</button> </td>';
$('#table').append(row);

$(".eliminar").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```